# Is it possible to customise drupal node reference and pass your search and a argument from another field

Tags: ajax, drupal, autocomplete, cck

I'm trying to create a bespoke form in drupal, with a node reference field.

I'd like to add a little extra functionality to the node reference auto complete. I've created a view, that contains an argument. I'd like to be able to pass that argument from a drop down as well as the typed text into the autocomplete script.

Does anyone know how I'd start this off.

```
/* FIELD 1 - the drop down  */
    $sql = "SELECT nid, title  FROM node where type='resourcetype' AND status =1 order by title
    ";
       $result = db_query($sql);
     $counter = 0 ;
     $options = array();
      while ($data = db_fetch_array($result)) {
       // krumo ($data);
      $options[$data[nid] ] =     $data[title]   ;
      if ($counter ==0 ) {$df = $data[nid]; }
      $counter ++;


      }


/* FIELD 2 - the node reference field  */    
         $form['sor']['type'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Resource type'),
      '#required' =>TRUE,
      '#options' => $options,
      )     ;


      $form['sor']['field_asor_sors'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Add a SOR item to this job'),
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'nodereference/autocomplete/field_asor_sors',
           '#element_validate' => array('myelement_validate_is_valid_noderef'),
      '#required' =>TRUE,

      );
```

Many Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy way to do this.

I wanted to do something similar a while ago (using different arguments based on node context), but refrained from doing it, since it would've needed some significant changes of the autocomplete callback logic. You'd need to change several nodereference functions to add support for passing an argument to the initial callback `nodereference_autocomplete()`, passing it on from there to `_nodereference_potential_references()`, and finally to `_nodereference_potential_references_views()`, while ensuring that the changes don't break anything else.

If you want to try nonetheless, you should take a look at the patches in [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/473670), as they also want to do something like that and might contain some useful hints/examples.

A potentially easier alternative might be to exchange the `#autocomplete_path` callback of the nodereference field with your own custom version that would generate the result, while adding js logic to your dropdown to add an additional argument to that path when the selection changes.

Comment: quote - "A potentially easier alternative might be to exchange the #autocomplete_path callback of the nodereference field with your own custom version that would generate the result, while adding js logic to your dropdown to add an additional argument to that path when the selection changes."

Do you know what format the auto complete result is served up in?
Am I correct in thinking I need to pass my array of results into drupal_js($arrayofresults); ?

Comment: @Matt: Take a look at the `nodereference_autocomplete()` function in nodereference.module. Basically it should be just a drupal_json($arrayofresults), but I guess you'd need to match the expected array key structure to allow nid extraction (not sure though).

Answer (score -1):

If you go into the nodereference field configuration form, and scroll all the way to the bottom, there's a fieldset (which may be collapsed) that is titled 'Advanced - Nodes that can be referenced (View)'.  You can use this to select a view and have that view be the source of the nodereference choices without writing any new code.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply.
I need to pass the arguments in, from a id from another field (FIELD 1), so it's not really answered the question..