# Drupal Nodereference in a custom form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-fapi

I have a custom Drupal FAPI form that supports a fairly complex workflow and I would like to add a Nodereference field to it.  Although I've found people who have included Nodereference fields on custom forms, I have been unable to find any examples of the FAPI declaration for the field (other than this question which uses a text field with the Nodereference AHAH callback: [Is it possible to customise drupal node reference and pass your search and a argument from another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763720/is-it-possible-to-customise-drupal-node-reference-and-pass-your-search-and-a-argu)).

So: what is the best way to add a Nodereference field to a custom form (FAPI)?

Bonus question: is there a simple way to allow for multiple values like CCK supports in a node form?
[image: Multivalue Nodereference Field in CCK Node]

Comment: As an additional note: I'm not worried about trying to create nodes in-line. We can assume that any nodes I want to reference have already been created.

Answer (score 2):

Starting learning ahah here: ['add another item' in non-CCK Drupal forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836549/add-another-item-in-non-cck-drupal-forms)

Someone who try investigate this: http://drupal.org/node/266584#comment-870376

Comment: Thanks for the pointers: looks like the info you provided would cover the 'bonus' part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to check the article: Adding dynamic form elements using AHAH http://drupal.org/node/331941

Comment: Please try summarizing the content of the link incase it dies or rots.